# Scalaz Streams vs Rx Java

Tags: scalaz, rx-java

Scalaz-streams is a young but very promising library for stream processing, while RxJava seems more mature and stable.

With my limited knowledge of both, I can see as an important difference the support that scalaz-streams offer for resource management.

What are the other key differences?

Comment: Please provide web links to both libraries.

Answer (score 3):

They both do offer resource management (see RxJava's unsubscription model)

The main difference between them is that scalaz-streams are pull based and RxJava is push based.

With pull based streams consumers control the action, in push based it's producers.
With push based streams you'll have to handle backpressure somehow (for example 1000s of open websocket connections that push data to your server), whereas with pull based streams backpressure is not a problem, the consumer is controlling the action.

More on push vs pull in this talk: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nCxBEUyIBt0

Comment: in *pull based* mechanism, how do you know if you have missed any messages ?

Comment: @tuxdna as a consumer you never miss any messages, since you're the one who's pulling them out of the stream